# Redimensionar fotos de carrousel feito por Bootstrap e Javascript

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um carrousel feito por Javascript e Bootstrap. Ele recebe imagens de um banco baseado em um rank de cliques, mas as imagens são todas de tamanhos diferentes e acabam interferindo no display do carrousel, eu ja tentei mudar tamanhos em CSS inline por todo lado, mas não consigo resolver.

Segue meu código:

```
<div class="row col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <div id="carousel" style="width:100%;">

                        <?php foreach($ofertas as $indice => $teste): ?>
                            <img src="<?= Yii::getAlias('@web').$teste['ofe_imagem']?>" style="!important;"> 
                        <?php endforeach ?>

                    </div>
```

```
<script>

$('#carousel').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    arrows: true,
    nextArrow:'<button  style="position"class="right carousel-control"></button>',
    prevArrow:'<button style="z-index:5"class="left carousel-control"></button>',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    infinite: true,
    adaptativeHeight: true, 

});
```

-

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara posta uns prints ai de como as imagens aparecem no carrossel, só como o código e pelo relato não da pra entender bem... E qual versão do Bootstrap está usando?

Comment: Upei as imagens, e estou usando a versão mais recente do Bootstrap

Comment: Vc quer que as imagens ocupem todo o espaço branco até as bordas azuis?

Comment: Exato, quero que ela cubra toda a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Victor,

Vê se isso resolve seu problema. Pelo que eu entendi, isso vai te ajudar.

Dê uma dimensão fixa à sua imagem usando CSS como:

```
.carousel-inner> .item> img {
  largura: 640px;
  altura: 360px;
}
```

Comment: Apenas fechou a imagem, mas vou tentar continuar trabalhando nesse conceito

Comment: Fechou a imagem? como assim?

Comment: Consegui fazer, usando sua resposta e a do Pbras, muito obrigado!

Comment: Parabéns, se precisar de algo avisa.

Answer (score 0):

Exprimenta trocar

```
<div class="row col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
```

por

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
```

Estás a usar só 6 colunas das 12 de bootstrap, e opor isso fica o espaço em branco.

Comment: Consegui fazer, usando sua resposta e a do Renan Osorio, muito obrigado!